# Консольное приложение. Ограничение ввода символов с использованием метода ReadLine(). Kotlin

Tags: строки, kotlin

Я только начал изучать Kotlin и столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня есть две строки, которые считывают данные. Как ограничить ввод в консоль пользователю, что бы он смог ввести только определенное количество символов..

например: в первую строку, пользователь сможет ввести 2 символа, а во вторую 1.

Comment: Никак, либо считывайте всю строку и берите нужное количество символов, либо выводите ошибку о неправильном вводе

Comment: Консоль это поток данных, читая его с помощью `readLine` получите введенную строку только после нажатия Enter пользователем. А сколько он до этого введет символов контролировать невозможно. Как альтернатива, можно читать посимвольно из `System.in`

Answer (score 0):

В консоли нельзя ограничить количество символов, но можно использовать проверку в коде:

```
val array = arrayListOf<String>() // создаем пустой список
val string = readLine() // получаем строку
array += string!!.split(" ") // делим полученную строку, используя пробел, как разделитель, далее записываем в массив эти 2 числа.
if (array[0].length > 2) { // если длина первого элемента массива(первого числа) больше двух, то выполняем код ниже:
    println("Первое число должно быть меньше 2!")
}
if (array[1].length > 1) { // если длина второго элемента массива(второго числа) больше единицы, то выполняем код ниже:
    println("Второе число должно быть меньше 1!")
}
```